# Is there a better way to model in UML?

Tags: uml

I am attempting to create a model that will allow me to capture the owners, users & assets in a given organization. I seem to have hit a stumbling block as I am unable to answer the questions below as well as uncertain whether I have modelled it correctly.

1. How do I express ownership and user for a given asset?
2. How do I express the ownership and use values for an object e.g. the server object has a vendor value of IBM and is owned by ABC Corp and is used by DEF user.
3. Is there a way I can further decouple common attributes or properties e.g. name, location? Is there a need to further decouple this?
4. How do I assess behavioural constraints e.g. what happens if a user leaves an organization or an asset is damaged? Where do I capture this information if not in the model?

Example of model

[image]

**EDIT**

Further to the answers I have updated my model. Not sure if it is going down the right path.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Responding to OP comments:

Re. recording info on ownership etc. here's an example:
[image]

The key thing is that date acquired/sold etc. are attributes of the relationship between an Asset and an Organisation/User.  They aren't attributes of the participating classes.  In the example, Asset Use allows for many concurrent users whereas Asset Ownership only allows 1 owner at any given point. That's controlled by the multiplicity.

> there is a requirement to display the owner as well as users. How would I show this seeing that the asset is not a subclass or subtype of the owner or user class?

Your display page would pull information from the necessary classes, following the relationship.  A page isn't limited to showing info from a single class at a time.

> For example the name attribute under owner would have the name of the organization however the name attribute under server would have the name of the server i.e. FQDN.

OK: then you could have different datatypes for the two names.  Perhaps a simple String for Organisation and a specific FQDN for Asset.  But remember: that means *all* Assets must be named using an FQDN.  If only Computers are named with FQDN then put the name attribute on Computer, not Asset.  As an aside: it's pretty common for organisations to have a naming scheme for assets that's independent of the type of asset.  The only requirement is that it's unique.  I've shown this in diag above for example.  hth.

**End Edit**

Answering your specific questions:

> How do I express ownership [..] for a given asset?

Presumably that's what the `Organisation - Asset` Association covers?  If so, what's the multiplicity?  Presumably:

- Each Asset is owned by exactly one Organisation  Or can an asset be jointly owned?
- Each Organisation owns many (zero or more) assets?
- Do you need to record any info about the ownership - for example, when the asset was acquired, when it was sold, etc.  If so you'll need an association class to capture that.

> How do I express user for a given asset?

Similar questions to above.  Can many users use the same asset?  Concurrently or sequentially?  Do you need to record start/end dates for asset use?

> How do I express the [..] server object has a vendor value of IBM

You have this modelled with the `Asset.vendor` attribute - which may be sufficient.  However: do you need to capture any details for Vendors?  e.g. contact info, address, support contracts, etc.  If so you'll likely need to split out a separate Vendor class.

> Is there a way I can further decouple common attributes or properties e.g. name, location? Is there a need to further decouple this?

All 3 sub-classes have the same attributes.  That smells bad - it suggests they aren't really different.  Could you use one class (`Asset`) that captures all attributes - and has an extra "assetType" (or similar) with legal values "Server", "Destop", "Laptop"?  However: do you need to track assets that aren't computers of some type?  If so a single Asset class isn't flexible enough.

> How do I assess behavioural constraints e.g. what happens if a user leaves an organization or an asset is damaged?

Depends on your business requirement.  What needs to happen if a user leaves?  Should the asset simply have no Users?  In which case the relationship needs to be optional (0..*).

What does it mean for an asset to be damaged?  Do you need to record the damages?  If so you need another class.

> Where do I capture this information if not in the model?

If it's not in the model you can't record or change it.  So I'd be very wary of anything you think you need to capture that's not in the model.  More likely it means your model is incomplete and/or you're missing requirements.

Generally I'd recommend you put some further thought into the naming & multiplicity of the associations.  Doing so will undoubtedly raise questions about the requirements and/or domain constraints.  That'll help you get a model that stands a much better chance of meeting the requirements.

hth.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. There is no requirement at this stage that an asset can be jointly owned. This isn't to say it won't ever happen. How would model the possibility of it occurring? I don't understand your comment `Do you need to record any info about the ownership - for example, when the asset was acquired, when it was sold, etc. If so you'll need an association class to capture that.` I do need to record such information.

Comment: As for your question `Similar questions to above. Can many users use the same asset? Concurrently or sequentially? ` Yes multiple users can use the same asset and it may occur concurrently or sequentially. For example a database server would have concurrent users.

Comment: As for my question regarding run time objects, I meant to say that there is a requirement to display the owner as well as users. How would I show this seeing that the asset is not a subclass or subtype of the owner or user class?

Comment: As for the classes having common attributes, this is correct however they would have different values. For example the name attribute under owner would have the name of the organization however the name attribute under server would have the name of the server i.e. FQDN.

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b. Why are you using an association class as opposed to a concrete class for asset ownership & use?

Comment: Association classes are concrete classes - not abstract.  They cater for cases where the _association_ has attributes that don't belong in the participating classes.  Try putting the dates in the participating classes and work through some examples.  That should illustrate why the attributes belong in the association - not the participants.

Answer (score 3):

Your design seems to mach with your presentation of the problem. For the question 4, it really depends what you want to capture with your system. If an asset is damaged, does it need to still have a record in the system? If an user leaves its organization, what do you want to store in the memory of the system?

For the question 3, you could use a common abstract class, like that:

[asset ownership UML Class diagram http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/assetOwnership.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/assetOwnership.jpg)

You can use this [link](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_qXU1kN-_EDCcAYkxP_EeLA) if you want to make a copy and adapt this model.

Comment: Thanks Xaelis. Is there a better term than entity? I started with the same approach as you suggested however people I showed the model to were confused by the term entity. The reason I want to capture constraints such as damage is because it provides a historical context for aspects such as who was the user at that time, what was damaged and possibly replaced, etc. Finally how can I have an object display the run time values for ownership, users, etc especially if the asset is not a specialization or generalization of a user.

Comment: Maybe a better term than entity can be NamedElement or LocalizableElement. If you need history of a damage event, you cloud add a Damage class that can record all informations of a such event (date, location, user and organization at this time...).

Comment: Using a common base just because two classes share a name and location is highly questionable.  They subclasses should have some semantics in common; it shouldn't just be a convenience to save you typing.  However it's good your model has multiplicity and some roles defined.  They may or may not be right - that will depend on the requirements.  But the good thing is it raises the question.

Comment: Yes @sfinnie if the common class is only to save typing is it a bad design. It can be justify, for example, if there is some common behavior or relationships on a LocalizableElement.

Comment: @Xaelis: Yes - exactly - some common semantics.  OP doesn't mention any so in this case, based on what we know, it's not justifiable.  Of course other requirements may come to light that do motivate the base class. _If_ it was necessary, perhaps a better name in this context would be 'Party' - that would be in keeping with the Party-Role pattern nomenclature.

Comment: @sfinnie - The reason I am seeking a base class is so that I can in some way follow the open-closed principle and extend the subclasses and reuse the base class. Am I going about it the wrong way? For example the assets isn't limited to just computers or servers. It will also list assets such as mice, keyboards, headphones, etc.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: A Base Class for Asset would most likely make sense.  Not sure you need separate subclasses for Server, Destop & Laptop though since they all have the same attributes.  Per my answer, a single subclass - say 'Computer' or similar - would suffice.  I was questioning the need for the 'Entity' base class in Xaelis' model.  Based on what you've said, there isn't an obvious need for it.  If you do need it, look up the Party-Role pattern for ideas on naming. hth.

Comment: @sfinnie - Thanks sfinnie. I updated my model based on some of your comments. Not sure if I am going down the right path. Also I don't quite follow what you mean by `Party-Role' pattern.